# Error relating to session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Having a problem here. I have this login control. In the login button, I hold the session using this code.

```
 protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["username"] = Login1.UserName;
}
```

Then, when I try to retrieve back the session, it give an error.
What should I do? This is the code to retrieve the session.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Session["username"].ToString();
    Label9.Text = username;
}
```

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: what are you using more precisely, webforms or mvc?

Comment: @Color Shadow: That's all you have? this is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at initial Page_Load event only your code is checking Session variable. try using this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(! IsPostBack){
       string username = Session["username"].ToString();
       Label9.Text = username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the page is loaded I think Page_Load is called and then the session is not set yet.
do something like this:

```
if(Session["username"] != null)
{
    string username = Session["username"].ToString();
    Label9.Text = username;
}
```